# Expand alphanumeric range from variable in bash

Tags: bash, shell

I have a variable which contains two alphanumeric sequences separated by a hyphen. I need to expand these to the full inclusive range separated by spaces. Here are some examples to illustrate:

```
0-9     -> 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
a-h     -> a b c d e f g h
B-Z     -> B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z
95-101  -> 95 96 97 98 99 100 101
```

These match bash brace expansion format, so I was looking to use this e.g. `{0..9}`, but I can't find a way to put variables in the expansion. I can get each side of the expansion, and using `seq` I can expand the numeric ones, but haven't found a way to expand the alphabetic sequences.

Any solution is fine, whether it uses bash brace expansion, manually separates the sides and expands them through another function, or does anything else.